# How to ask a question about whether an item is "in stock" or not

Tags: phrase-usage, questions

Let's say I want to buy a specific loaf of bread called "Blocky". How should I ask the question about whether the store has it "in stock".

I tried "Do you have a Blocky loaf", but I am not sure if I am right.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any Blocky bread in stock?

Comment: @NES I don't know the right form to use. I wanted  to buy 1 loaf of a Blocky bread...

Comment: Ilan, @NES has given you the right form to use. It doesn't matter if you want to buy one loaf or four, that's a common, natural, and grammatical way to ask the question. Your next question might be, "Could you hold X loaves for me?" where X is the number of loaves you want to buy when you go to the store.

Comment: 'Do you have a single item of the loaf called Blocky for my acquisitional purposes'?

Comment: *Do you have any Blocky bread in stock? I'd like to buy a loaf.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking :

> Do you **have any** Blocky bread?

asks if the seller has any of that bread **at the moment**.

> Do you **have** Block bread?

usually means **Do you have any at the moment**, but can also mean:

> Do you **carry** Blocky bread?

which means: **is Blocky bread** something that you sell (though it may be sold out at the moment).

As to your suggestion :

> Do you have a Blocky loaf?

specifically asks if the seller has **one** Blocky loaf

> Customer: Do you have **a** Blocky loaf?
>   Seller: We have several, which one would you like?

That phrasing is also commonly used in :

> Seller: Do you have **a** Visa card?
>   Customer: I have two.
>   Seller: Either one will do.